# Error creating user cron in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I'm using a shell script to deploy my server. I have this line:

```
crontab -l | { cat; echo "0 0 0 0 0 some entry"; } | crontab -
```

How can I modify this line to run this cron as a system user called "test"? When I try this:

```
APPUSER="test"
crontab -u $APPUSER -l | { cat; echo "/10 * * * * somepath/bin/python somepath/cron.py"; } | crontab -
```

I get this error:

```
no crontab for test                                                                                  
"-":0: bad minute                                                                                     
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: leave out the final `|crontab -` to look at the generated crontab.

Comment: So it should just be: ```crontab -u $APPUSER -l | { cat; echo "/10 * * * * somepath/bin/python somepath/cron.py"; }```  ?

Comment: Yes, just for debugging. This output is the one the error complains about.

Comment: Also have a look at `man 5 crontab` for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must add a * before /10 to make it run every 10 minutes, and add -u $APPUSER to the last crontab call (to add it to $APPUSER's crontab). Something like:

```
APPUSER="test"
crontab -u $APPUSER -l | { cat; echo "*/10 * * * * somepath/bin/python somepath/cron.py"; } | crontab -u $APPUSER -
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I run this command it spits out "no crontab for test", but shouldn't it be showing me the cron?

Comment: If you run `crontab -u test -l` you should see now your new crontab entry. It showed that message because your test's crontab was initially empty.

Comment: Oh so the code first prints out the cron contents? Can we remove this bit please? Would it be this?: ```{ cat; echo "*/10 * * * * somepath/bin/python somepath/cron.py"; } | crontab -u $APPUSER -```

Comment: Yes, that sentence appends new entries to user's crontab. If you want to overwrite user's crontab to have only that entry, this should work: `echo "*/10 * * * * somepath/bin/python somepath/cron.py" | crontab -u $APPUSER -`